# unable to plot or print anything from python script in ROS

Tags: python, matplotlib, ros

I am beginner in ROS and this is my first post. I am trying to implement Iterative Closest Point (ICP) algorithm which takes 2 images, align them and calculated the errors metric using nearest neighbor technique. i am launching the ICP node from a launch file. but the ICP script in which all the algorithm is implemented not printing or plotting anything while there are no errors in whole process. launch file and ICP script are attached below.

launch file: `

```
    <launch>

    <!-- define arguments -->
    <arg name="map" default="test1"/>
    <arg name="test" default="$(arg map)"/>
    <arg name="slam" default="gmapping"/>

    <!-- Call ICP comparison node -->
    <node pkg="cob_bringup_sim" type="icp_map_comparison.py"
     name="map_comparison" output="screen" required="True"
     args="-i $(find cob_bringup_sim)/results/$(arg slam)/$(arg test).png
    -m $(find cob_bringup_sim)/maps/$(arg map).png"/>

    </launch>`
```

ICP Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import math
import icp
import argparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def read_image(im):
   height, width = im.shape
   black_pixels = np.sum(im == 0)

points = np.zeros((black_pixels, 3))

count = 0
for i in range(0, height):
    for j in range(0, width):
        if im[i, j] == 0:
            points[count, :] = np.array([i, j, 0])
            count = count + 1

return points


def test_match(map_name, image_name, tolerance, black_threshold):
   im_model_raw = cv2.imread(map_name, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
   _, im_model = cv2.threshold(
    im_model_raw, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

im_raw = cv2.imread(image_name, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
_, im = cv2.threshold(im_raw, black_threshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

points_model = read_image(im_model)
points = read_image(im)

np.random.shuffle(points_model)
extension = points.shape[0] - points_model.shape[0]
repetitions = math.ceil(float(extension)/len(points_model))
points_model_upsampled = np.append(
    points_model, np.repeat(points_model, repetitions, axis=0)[0:extension, :], axis=0)

T, distances, iterations = icp.icp(
    points, points_model_upsampled, tolerance=tolerance)

# Make C a homogeneous representation of B
points_transformed = np.ones((points.shape[0], 4))
points_transformed[:, 0:3] = points

# Transform C
points_transformed = np.dot(T, points_transformed.T).T

# finally calculate free area difference
_, im_free = cv2.threshold(im_raw, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('image', im_free)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
white_pixels = np.sum(im_free == 255)
white_pixels_model = np.sum(im_model_raw == 255)
white_space_error = white_pixels_model - white_pixels
print('Free space mapping error', float(white_space_error)/white_pixels_model*100, '%')

print('Transformation Matrix:', T)

print('Point distances:', distances)

print('Pixel squared error:', np.average(distances ** 2))

print('Number of iterations:', iterations)

plt.plot(points_transformed[:, 0], points_transformed[:, 1], 'bo')
plt.plot(points_model[:, 0], points_model[:, 1], 'ro')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
rospy.init_node('icp_map_comparison_node')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Calculates the minimal transformation between two maps.')
parser.add_argument('-m', '--map', type=str,
                    help='The input map name.')
parser.add_argument('-i', '--image', type=str,
                    help='The input image name.')
parser.add_argument('-t', '--tolerance', type=float,
                    help='ICP tolerance (default is 0.0001).', default=0.0001)
parser.add_argument('-b', '--threshold', type=int,
                    help='Binarize black threshold (default is 1).', default=50)
args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

test_match(args.map, args.image, args.tolerance, args.threshold)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the problem was the CV2.waitkey(0), program was waiting for the key to be pressed which didn't worked either then i changed it to CV2.waitkey(1) and i worked fine.